# how to handle passing of product category to the Products Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I used command below to create a ProductsController (Note: I'm new to Laravel and PHP)

```
php artisan make:controller ProductsController --model=Product
```

I see that it created a controller with an index() function like below:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}
```

What would be the best way to give it the ability to show products by category?  My thought is to make a route like this:
/products/{category}.  So, I created a Category Enum and added that as the parameter of the index function (see below).  But it does not work.  Because when I entered an url like this http://localhost:8000/admin/products/Parts, it does not hit the /products/{category} route.  Instead, it is hitting the "products/{product} ......... products.show" route.

```
// create a Category ENUM
namespace App\Enums;
enum Category: string
{
    case Parts = 'Parts';
    case Vehicles = 'Vehicles';
    case All = 'All';
} 

// Change the index method in the ProductsController to be like below
    public function index(Category $category)
{
    return $category->value;
}

// below is how I define the routes
Route::resource('products', ProductsController::class);
```

Comment: Show us how you defined your routes, please.

Comment: Here is how I defined it: Route::resource('products', ProductsController::class);.  I just added it to the original post.

Comment: Why do you intend to use "categories" by their "names" rather than "ids"?

Comment: In my DB, I  have a table call Decodes.  This is a generic table I use to store different types of codes.  For example, order status codes, production category codes, user type code, ....  So, I don't really have a specific Categories table in my DB.  Because of how my DB is designed, using "category id" wouldn't make sense in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a product belongs to a particular category, you should instead define your route as:

```php
Route::resource('categories.products', ProductsController::class);
```

That would generate the routes below:

```bash
$ php artisan route:list | grep "categories.products"
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/{category}/products                | categories.products.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@index                            | web          |
|        | POST      | categories/{category}/products                | categories.products.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@store                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/{category}/products/create         | categories.products.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@create                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/{category}/products/{product}      | categories.products.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@show                             | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | categories/{category}/products/{product}      | categories.products.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@update                           | web          |
|        | DELETE    | categories/{category}/products/{product}      | categories.products.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@destroy                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | categories/{category}/products/{product}/edit | categories.products.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@edit                             | web          |
```

In your frontend source code, you could use this URL path:

```bash
http://localhost:8000/admin/categories/Parts/products
```

Comment: Thanks Steven.  Awesome, that works.  Didn't like it being such a long path.  But I don't think I have a choice.